# How to assign child-to-parent in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, customization, uigesturerecognizer

I've made a UIElement class which inherit UIView class in order to make custom properties for my views.

The problem I've faced, as you can see the code, I can't assign a **UIElement** object to Gesture Recognizer's **view** property.

As long as UIElement is a child of UIView, I can't make child-to-parent relationship.

I'm thinking (alot) to figure out a solution, but I didn't find any.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIElement * element = [[UIElement alloc] init];
    element.name = @"A Name"; // Custom property


    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(responsToGesture:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.3;
    [longPress setDelegate:self];
    [element addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}


- (void)responsToGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    UIElement * element = sender.view; // Here's the problem: Incompatible pointer types
    NSLog(@"Element's Name: %@", element.name);
}
```

Comment: You have to add the gesture recognizer to your uielement.

Comment: and who keeps your `element` or `longPress` alive after the `–viewDidLoad` runs out of its scope? I guess your forgot to keep your objects alive...

Comment: Sorry I've edited the code.

Comment: Read up on "cast" in C.

Comment: Ok, I'll bite. What's a UIElement? Is that a Cocoa touch class? I can't find it anywhere. Is it a third party class? If so, is it a subclass of UIView? Objective-C does not have multiple inheritance, so if UIElement isn't a subclass of UIView, you can't make it into a UIView subclass.

Comment: @DuncanC -- Opie said "I've made a UIElement class which inherit UIView class."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast your `sender` in `UIelement`

```
- (void)responsToGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if ([sender.view isKindOfClass:[UIElement class]]) {
        UIElement * element = (UIElement *)sender.view;
    }
}
```

Comment: `UILongPressGestureRecognizer *` will always be the parameter. He needs to cast `sender.view` to `UIElement *`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add that `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your view, so `responsToGesture:` will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

I would just assert if `view` is not a `UIElement *`. Fail loudly to catch defects early.

```
- (void)responsToGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSParameterAssert([gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIElement class]]);

    UIElement * element = (UIElement *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    NSLog(@"Element's Name: %@", element.name);
}
```

Comment: The assert, of course, should be unnecessary, but is extra insurance when you don't quite know what you're doing (which is clearly the case here).